# Return only distinct values from one field in a MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've been searching around for some examples for this but none of them seem to work. I'm trying to return only unique values from one field where the conditions from another field are true. Here is what my collection looks like:

Records

```
{
 _id: "XuZcMm2MGCr7CshB5"<br>
 clientAvailability: "Direct Solutions<br>
"enhancementId: "D08F817L"<br>
enhancementName: "Allow TN Transfer"<br>
follow: false<br>
impactedProducts: Array[4]<br>
internal: false<br>
like: false<br>
releaseDate: Wed Aug 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)<br>
requestingMso: "Internal"<br>
requestingProduct: "Voice Services"<br>
required: false<br>
}
```

I tried to limit my query to only documents where the 'releaseDate' is in 2014 and return all of the unique values of 'clientAvailability' for those records. Why isn't this working? I'm a noob, so I''m sure I'm missing something simple. Thanks in advance!

```
    return Records.distinct('clientAvailability', { $and: [{releaseDate: {$gte: new Date('Jan 1, 2014'), $lte: new Date('Nov 26,2014')}}]}
    );
```

Comment: Your date in the record looks like a string rather than a date type.

Answer (score 1):

[`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct) is an async function so you need to provide a callback to receive the results.  You're currently just returning the `Query` object it represents.  You also don't need to use the `$and` operator.

```
Records.distinct('clientAvailability', 
    {releaseDate: {$gte: new Date('Jan 1, 2014'), $lte: new Date('Nov 26,2014')}},
    function (err, result) {
        // result contains the array of unique values
    }
);
```